# Vercel - Deploying something.vercel.app searchable on google?

Tags: search, vercel

I'm new to Vercel and have deployed a nextjs master version from bitbucket to production. It deployed successfully and it's been live now for about a week, but I'm unable to search for it in google. Are the *.vercel.app domains (out of the box) searchable? Does it take a few weeks? Or is there additional configurations that need to be done?

I tried google search console, but was unsure how to configure the out of the box vercel.app url. I looked at this
https://www.lukaspolak.com/blog/how-to-verify-google-search-console-domain-with-vercel, but this is for an additional domain to which you add to your project.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use google search console with vercel.app domain you need to use URL prefix in google search console

For app router download the file that google provides and host it in your Public folder